# How to use where query in Google Spreadsheet with filter multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some of the scenario for the google sheets filtering and brings the data to another sheets. Having some issue on combining with multiple AND when using "Where". It does not show result after apply for the syntax. I was wondering how if we want to filtering more than 1, maybe have 2,3,4,5 data to filter. How do we really make it in the query GoogleSheets, please help me to have more clearer understanding on the "where" query with multiple conditions. Thank you so much!

Here is the link of the google sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RNku0Bpj-hbBkKcfGjfJ_CU9gQbWAz6MxGAlK5oGOl0/edit?usp=sharing

**Scenario1:** Get date in September(B)

**Scenario2:** Get the data that's show Green, Red(A)

**Scenario3:** Get the date that filling in billed date(D) also is September

[image]

The formula that I'm trying to apply is failed to run....

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select SUM(C) WHERE B >= DATE'2021-09-01' AND B<=Date'2021-09-30'AND A='Blue' AND A='Green' AND ISDATE(D) ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A can't be at the same time Blue and Green. So try

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select SUM(C) WHERE B >= DATE'2021-09-01' AND B<=Date'2021-09-30' AND (A='Blue' OR A='Green' OR A='Red') and D>=DATE'2021-09-01' AND D<=Date'2021-09-30' ")
```

[image]

Comment: But how if I wanted the group with Blue or Green together with the filter on September. It's only allow for one? Which mean I wanted to sum the amount that have in group Blue and Green in September

Comment: When using the code that you propose to me Blue or Green is work cool bro. I'm understand the logic but once with "AND ISDATE(D)" this formula not going to work again

Comment: share a sample please!

Comment: Replace by `AND D IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Have been edited share the link on the top. Thank you for your patient

Comment: ok, and you have changed the goal ...I have updated my answer

Comment: Cool man! Thank a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

=FILTER(A2:D,MONTH(B2:B)=9,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"Red|Green"),MONTH(D2:D)=9)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).